# Exporting Gradle Project with Libaries

Tags: java, gradle, export

Iam trying to export a Gradle-Project running on a LWJGL libary. So when i try to export it using:
`gradlew clean build`
it finishes a build, but when i run it it crashes directly with the Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWKeyCallbackI
        at strobe.app.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallbackI
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I believe i got this Error before when i tryied to export an Project with libaries and forgot to include them in the jar. So how do i include the libaries in the gradle Build Jar. Because i always thought that Gradle would do that for me =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the greatest documentation to resolve your issue. plz make sure that your project file structure was correct and recheck your project's `build.gradle` file

1. [Gradle Documentation] [1](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/)
2. this is may not be related to ur question but the idea form those, there are so many repositories on github plz go through it. as an example use the following repository and generate .jar file Springboot with gradle

   [Repository Link](https://github.com/LalithK90/springboot-Thymeleaf-Teaching-Material)